# How to enable, then disable, then enable a constraint again?

Tags: swift, constraints

I want to make a button to active and deactivate a constraint but my problem is when i enable->disable->enable it, I get a fatal error.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightEmail: NSLayoutConstraint!

if alamatDomisiliSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    heightEmail.isActive=true
    heightEmail.constant=8
    print("tidak")
} else if alamatDomisiliSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    heightEmail.isActive=false
    print("ya")
}
```

Comment: post the crash and where you put this code ?

Comment: i got this error 
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: where you put the code ??

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are using **isActive**. 
The logic would be simple. when you want it to disAppear make its height 0 and when show make its height back to 8

```
 if alamatDomisiliSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {                   
              heightEmail.constant=8
            print("tidak")

        }else if alamatDomisiliSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{  
                heightEmail.constant=0 // Assuming you want to hide here
         print("ya")
        }
```

Comment: it works but how to make it the constraint relative not using constant

Comment: Sorry did not understand your question.? Can you explain more

Comment: oh it works ! i thought if i set the constraint to constant if i use bigger phone the constraint will look mess

Comment: you can give condition device wise. If i understood you correctly. You want is that you need to give the constant for each device. In that case just give a simple condition like E.g: if iphone5{ height = 30}elseif iphone 6{ height = 40}

Comment: @IndraSen You stated that you are getting the error "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Now you state that this answer works. But this answer would not solve that error. Did you fix that error separately from the change in this answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if alamatDomisiliSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
heightEmail.isActive = true
heightEmail.constant = 8
print("tidak")
} else if alamatDomisiliSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
    heightEmail.constant = 0 //disappear   
    heightEmail.isActive=false
    print("ya")
}
```

Comment: Explain how your code is different from OP's code

Comment: Check the code.

Comment: Explain how this code solves the "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

Comment: Are you sure (heightEmail.constant = 0) will resolve the above mentioned crash